# Python - InvalidArgumentException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to start webscraping, but whenever I try to acces an URL I get an error message.

My code is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('www.python.org')
```

This opens a new Chrome window, but that's all it does.

The error message I get is the following:

```
InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

I work with Spyder, which I get from Anaconda, and my chromedriver.exe is in the both in the Anaconda3 folder and the Spyder folder.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL is not Valid , it has to start with `http://`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

try:
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get('http://www.python.org')
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
finally:
  if driver is not None :
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include executable path and try below solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

Your url is not correct `www.python.org` , correct url : `https://www.python.org`